# Use Powershell script to display just alias name column

Tags: powershell, formatting

I'm fairly new to powershell scripting after years of unix/linux scripting and I'm still trying to get the handle of object output. I am trying to run the Get-Alias command to return just the column "Name." When I try to select just the column "name" I either get the whole get-alias output, or errors. 
The script/ command line I am trying to use is: `get-alias | format-table`

When I add `select-object` logic, it either cuts off the name of the alias and leaves off the command name or the `select-object` logic is just ignored. I'm sure the solution is simple. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select the values of one property on all objects of an array in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176815/select-the-values-of-one-property-on-all-objects-of-an-array-in-powershell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

```
PS> Get-Alias | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName

? -> Where-Object                                                                                              
cd -> Set-Location 
...
```

That is, the true property name underlying the `Name` *display column* is `DisplayName`.

---

**PowerShell's default output formatting *sometimes* uses column names that differ from or the underlying objects' property names (which is the case here) and/or use *values* that are *calculated*.**

What shows as column `Name` by default is actually the underlying objects' `.DisplayName` property, whereas the true `.Name` property contains just the alias' own name.

You can inspect the members (properties and methods) of an object's type via `Get-Member` or, to see both the property (but not method) names and their concrete *values* for a given object, pipe to `Format-List *`:

```
PS> Get-Alias | Select-Object -First 1 | Format-List *

HelpUri             : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423
ResolvedCommandName : Where-Object
DisplayName         : ? -> Where-Object
ReferencedCommand   : Where-Object
ResolvedCommand     : Where-Object
Definition          : Where-Object
Options             : ReadOnly, AllScope
Description         : 
OutputType          : {}
Name                : ?
CommandType         : Alias
Source              : 
Version             : 
Visibility          : Public
ModuleName          : 
Module              : 
RemotingCapability  : None
Parameters          : {[InputObject, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [FilterScript, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [Property, 
                      System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata], [Value, System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata]...}
ParameterSets       :
```

---

#### Optional reading: How to inspect a given type's formatting data:

For background information, see [`Get-Help about_Format.ps1xml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml).

`Get-Alias` outputs `[System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo]` instances (as `Get-Member` will tell you).

Using the `Get-FormatData` cmdlet you can inspect a type's formatting data:

**Caveat**: Not all formatting data in effect is by default reported by `Get-FormatData` for backward-compatibility reasons - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4237); notable omissions are `[System.IO.FileInfo]` and `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`, as returned by `Get-ChildItem` / `Get-Item` ; in short, **to see *all* formatting data in effect for the PowerShell version at hand, use**:

```
Get-FormatData -PowerShellVersion $PSVersionTable.PSVersion [...]
```

Somewhat ironically, there is no custom formatting data defined for the `System.Management.Automation.ExtendedTypeDefinition` instances that `Get-Format` outputs, and the default formatting isn't helpful.

**Currently, the simplest way to inspect formatting data is to pipe to the `Format-Custom` cmdlet**, which provides an informal, human-readable representation of the internal structure of objects:

```
# Best to send this to a file and open that file in a text editor for perusal.
$prev, $FormatEnumerationLimit = $FormatEnumerationLimit, [int]::MaxValue
Get-FormatData System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo | Format-Custom -Depth 10
$FormatEnumerationLimit = $prev
```

Note:

- `$FormatEnumerationLimit` is temporarily set to the highest possible value to ensure that *all* column / property definitions are shown in the output (by default, only up to *4* would be shown, and omitted ones would be indicated with `...` (Windows PowerShell, 3 chars.) / `…` (PowerShell Core, 1 char.).
- `-Depth 10` ensures that the internal structure of the output objects is fully represented; by default, only up to *5* levels would be.

The output will *look vaguely* like JSON, and is suited to visual inspection only, not programmatic processing.

You'll see one or more of the following blocks:

```
class ExtendedTypeDefinition
{
  TypeNames = 
    [
      <typeName>
    ]

  FormatViewDefinition = 
    [
      class FormatViewDefinition
      {
        Name = <formatName>
        Control = 
          class <viewType>Control
        ...
      }
      class FormatViewDefinition
      {
        Name = <formatName>
        Control = 
          class <viewType>Control
        ...
      }
}
```

- `<typeName>` is the full type name to which the format applies (e.g., `System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo`)
- `<formatName>` is an internally used, non-standardized name for the format-definition at hand
- `<viewType>Control` is one of the following classes, defining the views for use with the corresponding `Format-Table,`Format-List, `Format-Wide`, and `Format-Custom` cmdlets: `TableControl`, `ListControl`, `WideControl`, `CustomControl`, all derived from the [`System.Management.Automation.PSControl` base class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscontrol).

Note that the output may contain *duplicate* information, as it does in the case of `System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo` (because the formatting information is repeated for all *other* command types that share the same formatting), but it is sufficient to examine the *first* `class <viewType>Control` instance of interest.

Specifically, here's an excerpt from the first `class TableControl` block:

```
class TableControl   # Defines the format for Format-Table
{
  Headers =   # The table headers (column names and column properties)
      ...
      class TableControlColumnHeader # The "Name" column *header*
      {
        Label = Name
        Alignment = Undefined
        Width = 50
      }
      ...
    ]

  Rows =  # The table rows (underlying or calculated property values)
    [
      class TableControlRow
      {
        Columns = 
          [
            ...
            class TableControlColumn  # The "Name" column *value*
            {
              Alignment = Undefined
              DisplayEntry = 
                class DisplayEntry
                {
                  ValueType = ScriptBlock  #  A *calculated* property 
                  Value = 
                                                  if ($_.CommandType -eq "Alias")
                                                  {
                                                    $_.DisplayName
                                                  }
                                                  else
                                                  {
                                                    $_.Name
                                                  }

                }
              FormatString = 
            }
            ...
    ]
    ...
```

Note that the header and column-value definitions are matched *positionally*; e.g., the 2nd `TableControlColumn` instance defines the value for the 2nd `TableControlColumnHeader` instance.

The above explains why, even though the column is entitled "Name", it is an alias' `.DisplayName` property that is displayed, whereas all the other command types are represented by their `.Name` property, by way of the embedded *script* block (the piece of PowerShell code in which `$_` represents the input object at hand).

Presumably, the decision to show the `.DisplayName` for aliases was made to provide more helpful information by default, but the discrepancy between the column name and underlying property name can certainly lead to confusion.

Note that there is also a *dedicated* table view for type `[System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo]` that (a) defines only 2 columns, and (b) calls the `.DisplayProperty` column values by their true name.
However, as of the PowerShell versions listed above, this view is *preempted* by the multi-type definition discussed above and effectively *ignored*.