# Powershell - Get object properties displayed in console

Tags: powershell, object, variables

The point is to populate a variable with a Powershell object's property name displayed in a console.
Meaning, if I run `Get-Process`, I only want the eight object's properties returned in the console which are 'Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName'.

`Get-Member` command is not helpful here.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thank you all!

Comment: You _can_ extract the formatting data that PowerShell internally uses for the Process tableview - but all the property values (even the numeric ones) are going to be converted to _strings_, limiting their usefulness somewhat. Would that still be useful to you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mathias. I guess I can do that with an `Out-String`. Am I right?

Comment: if you want just those properties ... then either `Select-Object` them OR make a `[PSCustomObject]` with the desired props.

Comment: @Charlypop No, `Out-String` gives you one big multi-line string. What I'm talking about is exactly what you ask for - constructing a proper object with a 'WS(K)' property for example, but the value stored in `$object.'WS(K)'` is going to be a _string_ `"24.5"` instead of a decimal value `24.5`. Would that work?

Comment: The point is to make the output dynamic. I may also want to get the properties' names from `Get-Service` command but the thing is I do not want to have to think about which properties to output. `Select-Object` would force me to list the properties so would `$object.PROPERTY`. Hope this is clear for you

Comment: `Get-FormatData System.Diagnostics.Process` would give you all information, but as @MathiasR.Jessen already wrote, this gives you only string representation of the properties, intended for display purposes only. That can't be relied upon - the formatting could even change in future PowerShell versions. What is the broader picture here, for what purpose do you need these properties?

Comment: @zett42, for the culture mainly

Comment: @Charlypop, Mathias noted that just getting the column _names_ may not be what you were looking for - please see the updated answer (new middle section).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the ***column* names**  - which may or may not be *property* names - **of the *table view*** that is presented for a given .NET type *if it has [predefined formatting data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml)* (that includes a table view) associated with it:

- Note:

  - The following is a proper, but nontrivial and limited solution that derives the column names from the formatting data, using the *first* table-view definition found. It also has conceptual background information.

    - See the **bottom section** for a **quick-and-dirty solution for *getting the column names only***, which uses text parsing to extract the column names directly from a given command's formatted output.
  - The **middle section** builds on this first section and **extracts a list of property names and calculated properties mirroring the column definitions, which can be used with `Select-Object`**, in order to create custom objects that have properties with the same values that the formatting data produces.

```sh
# Determine the .NET type of interest.
$type = (Get-Process)[0].GetType()

# Extract the names of the column headers from the *first* table-view definition.
Get-FormatData $type -PowerShellVersion $PSVersionTable.PSVersion | 
  ForEach-Object FormatViewDefinition | 
    Where-Object Control -is [System.Management.Automation.TableControl] | 
      Select-Object -First 1 |
        ForEach-Object { 
          $i = 0
          $rows = $_.Control.Rows
          foreach ($colLabel in $_.Control.Headers.Label) {
            if ($colLabel) { $colLabel } # Explicit label, with a calculated column value or renamed property
            else           { $rows.Columns[$i].DisplayEntry.Value } # Property name, with its value as the column value.
            ++$i
          }
        }
```

*Caveat*: The above limits output to the *first* table-view definition found - which may or may not apply to a given command. Which definition is chosen *by default* is potentially governed by criteria associated with the definitions that select based on runtime conditions, including selecting by specific input type, given that a single instance of formatting data can cover *multiple* types.
Also note that views may involve *grouping* (as you see in `Get-ChildItem`'s formatted output, for instance), and the grouping criterion isn't covered by the command above.
Note that even for a single type *multiple views* may be defined, and in order to use a non-default one you must request it explicitly, via `Format-Table`'s `-View` parameter, assuming you know the name,<sup>[1]</sup> e.g. `Get-Process | Format-Table -View StartTime)`.

- See also:

  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45046908/45375) for how to inspect formatting data *in full*.

    - You can alternatively pipe `Get-FormatData` output to [`Export-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-formatdata) in order to export formatting data to an XML file, which has the disadvantage of being hard to read, but has the advantage of matching the XML schema used for *authoring* formatting data - see next point - whereas the in-memory types used to represent formatting data partially use property names that don't match the underlying XML elements.
  - As for *authoring* formatting data, which as of PowerShell 7.2.2 requires *XML files* (`*.Format.ps1xml`):

    - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526714/45375) for an example of how to define your own table view.
    - [Formatting File Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) and the [Format Schema XML Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/format-schema-xml-reference?view=powershell-7.2)

Note:

- Using `-PowerShellVersion $PSVersionTable.PSVersion` with [`Get-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-formatdata) is only needed in *Windows PowerShell*, for certain types, to work around a bug that is no longer present in *PowerShell (Core) 7.1+*
- While *column* names *typically* correspond to the *property* names of the type instances being formatted, that isn't always the case, such as with the [`[System.Diagnostics.Process]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process) instances output by [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process).

  - A *general caveat*, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) notes, is that *display formatting* of types isn't part of the public contract regarding breaking changes, so formatting definitions are allowed to change over time.
- If a given type has *no* predefined formatting data associated with it (in which case `Get-FormatData` is a quiet no-op):

  - The names of its (public) instance properties are used as column
    names.
  - You only get a *table* view by default if there are *4 or fewer properties* but you can request it explicitly with [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) (With *5 or more properties*, [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) is applied by default).
  - To get the names of all (public) instance properties of a given object, use the [intrinsic `.psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject), which is a rich source of reflection; e.g.:

    - `(Get-Process | Select-Object -First 1).psobject.Properties.Name`

---

**To create a list of property names and [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) usable with `Select-Object` that mirror the formatting-data's column definition:**

```sh
# Determine the .NET type of interest.
$type = (Get-Process)[0].GetType()

# Get an array of property names / calculated properties from the
# formatting data, for later use with Select-Object
$props = 
Get-FormatData $type -PowerShellVersion $PSVersionTable.PSVersion | 
  ForEach-Object FormatViewDefinition | 
    Where-Object Control -Is [System.Management.Automation.TableControl] | 
      Select-Object -First 1 |
        ForEach-Object { 
          $i = 0
          $rows = $_.Control.Rows
          foreach ($colLabel in $_.Control.Headers.Label) {
            if ($colLabel) { # Explicit label, with a calculated column value or renamed property
              @{ 
                Name = $colLabel
                Expression = if ('ScriptBlock' -eq $rows.Columns[$i].DisplayEntry.ValueType) {
                               [scriptblock]::Create($rows.Columns[$i].DisplayEntry.Value) 
                             } else { 
                               $rows.Columns[$i].DisplayEntry.Value
                             } 
              } 
            }
            else { # Property name, with its value as the column value.
              $rows.Columns[$i].DisplayEntry.Value
            }
            ++$i
          }
        }

# Sample call
Get-Process | Select-Object -Property $props | Format-Table | more
```

- The sample call produces similar output to just `Get-Process` alone, as it uses the column definitions as (calculated) properties - albeit with default values for formatting attributes such as column width and alignment.
- Note the explicit use of `Format-Table` to ensure *tabular* output; without it - given that the `[pscustomobject]` instances created by `Select-Object` have no formatting data associated with them - *list*  formatting (implied `Format-List`) would result.
- As Mathias points out, the *calculated* properties will be *string*-typed even for columns based on *numeric* properties, because their purpose in the formatting data is to created formatted string representations.

---

**Quick-and-dirty solution for getting the *column names only***:

The following uses [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) `-Stream` in conjunction with [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) to extract the column names from a given command's formatted output, which relies on two assumptions:

- The column names have no embedded spaces
- The command actually produces *table*-formatted output by default; however, you can insert a `Format-Table` call before `Out-String`, if desired.

```sh
Get-Process | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -List '^\s*--+' -Context 1, 0 |
  ForEach-Object { -split $_.Context.PreContext[0] }
```

Output:

```sh
NPM(K)
PM(M)
WS(M)
CPU(s)
Id
SI
ProcessName
```

Note: In *Windows PowerShell* an additional property shows, as the first one: `Handles`.

---

<sup>[1] While tab-completion does offer view names, they appear to be out of sync with the actually available ones, as of PowerShell 7.2.2. To see the latter, provoke an error with a *dummy* name, and the error message will list the available ones; e.g. `Get-Process | Format-Table -View NoSuch` lists the following available views in the resulting error message: `process, Priority, StartTime`</sup>

Comment: Awesome answer mklement0! specially the first code snippet to get a better understanding on how default formatting is constructed for different object types