# PowerShell Array output format

Tags: powershell

In Power Shell I try to get all members of an AD group with the following command:

```
$users=Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'AD-Group-XYZ' -Recursive | Select SamAccountName
```

Then if I try to print the first username by typing:

```
$users[0]
```

I get the following output:

```
SamAccountName
--------------
usenameX
```

The question is how can I get only the output:

```
usenameX
```

and skip:

```
SamAccountName
--------------
```

I tried the following but nothing works:

```
$users[0].ToString()
$users[0].text
$users[0].text.ToString()
```

The reason is that I want to iterate in all usernames and create a string where I concatenate them and split them with a space.

Comment: Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` instead of just `Select-Object`.

Comment: You can also do `$users[0].sAMAccountName`.

Comment: depending on the version of PS you have, $users.samAccountName should return the entire list.

Comment: A similar effect can be achieved using `ForEach-Object { $_.SamAccountName }`.

Comment: Or shorthand for lit's suggestion is `$users | % SamAccountName` (which accomplishes the same thing as Bill's suggestion, it's just faster to type and harder to understand).

Comment: All valid suggestions here; if you're interested in their relative performance, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/45375

Comment: Thanks to all! All inputs were valid.