# Extract or Dereference `Name` property from Piped Objects in Powershell

Tags: powershell, write-host

What is the proper way to specify the `Name` part of the object after a pipe?

**Actual Answer** Remove the `Select` from the pipe and go direct such as

`dir $staging | Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan`

---

**Setup**
I am doing a directory listing to the output and I want to use `Write-Host` to achieve that, but what is need to discriminate out the object boxing and just show `Name`.

**Command** `dir | select Name | Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan`

but the output to the console looks like this

[image: nce]

---

How can this be done to show just the values of `Name`?

Comment: In the linked duplicate, I recommend [mklement0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/3905079) as it's the most complete and up-to-date.

Comment: @briantist that answer didn't work for `-ExpandProperty Name` gave this error: `Write-Host : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command 
either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its 
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.`

Comment: I put the actual answer in the post since this is closed.

Comment: `(dir).name | write-host -fore darkcyan`

Comment: Thanks @xon that is a good one.