# How to get only the uptime of the server on Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following code, It's work when I use directly within powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select @{LABEL=’LastBootUpTime’;EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)
```

And it returns:

```
LastBootUpTime
--------------
14/09/2019 10:41:50
```

But when I use the command within a Powershell script `.ps1` with invoke-command the output returns more informations:

```
LastBootUpTime        PSComputerName RunspaceId                          
--------------        -------------- ----------                          
9/14/2019 10:41:50 AM 192.168.0.20   af08d2d8-c4f1-4f85-9d6c-e3f4ffe475c6
```

Why this happen?

If possible, I'd like without the header LastBootUpTime too.

Comment: Invoke-Command will always return additional information, in this case  where the command was run and the runspace id.

Comment: As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., `Get-CimInstance`) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., `Get-WmiObject`) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell _Core_, where all future effort will go, doesn't even _have_ them anymore. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508009/45375).

Answer (score 4):

Invoke-Command will always return additional information, in this case  where the command was run and the runspace id. You can always get results into a variable and simply print out the property you want.E.g.

```
$result = invoke-command {your-command}
$result.LastBootUpTime
```

or for short

```
(invoke-command {your-command}).LastBootupTime
```

Note that when you are using wmi, you do not need to necessarily use invoke-command, you can also directly pass -computer parameter to it to run the command against a remote computer:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -computer "remote_computer_name"
```

Comment: Nice; worth adding: The WMI cmdlets were superseded by the CIM cmdlets in PowerShell version 3, and, unlike the WMI cmdlets, which use the firewall-unfriendly DCOM remoting, the CIM cmdlets (with the `-ComputerName` and `-CimSession` parameters) use the same firewall-friendly remoting transport as PowerShell's general-purpose remoting. On a minor note: `Invoke-Command` only decorates the output objects when actual remoting is involved (with `-ComputerName` or `-Session[Name]` arguments - though there's rarely a good reason to use `Invoke-Command` for local execution).

Answer (score 3):

Since **you're ultimately only interested in the (transformed) property *value***, there's ***no need to use `Select-Object`* (whose alias is `select`) at all - use `ForEach-Object` instead**:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem |
  ForEach-Object { $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime) }
```

<sup>Note: The extra properties you saw, added by a remote `Invoke-Command` call with a `-ComputerName` argument (described below), are still technically *present* on the result, but they won't *display*.</sup>

That said, **the WMI cmdlets were *deprecated* in PowerShell version 3**.   **Using `Get-CimInstance` in lieu of `Get-WmiObject`** actually makes the `.ConvertToDateTime()` call unnecessary (the `.LastBootUpTime` now directly contains a `[datetime]` instance), in which case you can **simply use `Select-Object`'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter** in order to return the property *value* only (rather than *a `[pscustomobject]` instance* with the requested property):

```
Get-CimInstance CIM_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastBootUpTime
```

Note: **`Get-CimInstance` directly supports a `-ComputerName` argument**, so you don't need `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` for the invocation; unlike the firewall-unfriendly DCOM protocol that the WMI cmdlets use, **the CIM cmdlets use the same, firewall-friendly transport as [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq)**.

Or, **more succinctly and efficiently**, especially in a case such as this where the command returns only a *single* object, **use *direct property access***:

```
(Get-CimInstance CIM_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/45375) contrasts the pros and cons of these two approaches and shows other alternatives.

---

As for **what you tried**, which generally relates to:

#### Managing the origin properties automatically added by remote operations:

**In *remoting* scenarios, PowerShell *decorates* the objects returned with *additional properties* that provide *origin information***.  These properties are (mostly) of type `NoteProperty` and are added:

- when [*PowerShell remoting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq) is involved - such as via `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` in your case.
- when [CIM cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/) such as `Get-CimInstance` are *directly* used remotely, such as with the 
  `-ComputerName` parameter.

These properties are:

- `.PSComputerName` (the name of the remote computer on which the code was executed)

  - Note: On objects returned from remote CIM calls, `.PSComputerName` appears as a regular property (type `Property`), not a `NoteProperty`.
- The associated hidden `.PSShowComputerName` property, which defaults to `$true`, which explains why you saw a `PSComputerName` column in the display output.

  - If you capture the objects *before* printing them to the screen, you can set the property to `$false` on them, in which case their `.PSComputerName` property won't show (but will still be there) - however, the `.RunspaceId` property may - situationally - *still* show, and would have to be explicitly excluded - see below.
- PowerShell remoting only (not remote CIM calls): `.RunspaceId` (the ID of the remote runspace)

To **exclude these from local display / presence on the object**, use the following techniques:

- **If you're only interested in *select properties***, make the `Select-Object` call *locally*, which, by virtue of locally constructing new `[pscustomobject]` instances with the properties of interest only, implicitly excludes the remoting-added properties:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ... { ... } |
  Select-Object Name, LastBootUpTime  # LOCAL call to Select-Object
```

- **If you're interested in all properties *except* the remoting-added ones**, use 
  `Select-Object -ExcludeProperty` to eliminate them explicitly:

```
# Get remote output, then locally exclude the remoting-added properties.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ... { ... } |
  Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName, RunSpaceId
```

<sup>Note: `Select-Object` generally returns `[pscustomobject]` instances whose properties are *static copies* of the input objects and which lack the input type's *methods*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I found one way! if someone to need here is:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select @{LABEL=’LastBootUpTime’;EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}|Select-Object -ExpandProperty  lastbootuptime
```

Here is how I used (I'm creating a report in HTML for my database)

```
write-output "<p> Horario do Ultimo boot: $(Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select @{LABEL=’LastBootUpTime’;EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}|Select-Object -ExpandProperty  lastbootuptime)</p>"
```

The output was (in my language and region):

```
Horario do Ultimo boot: 09/14/2019 10:41:50
```

Comment: That works, but is inefficient (and verbose, with duplication); you can do without `Select-Object` altogether, if all you're interested in is the _value_ of the `$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)` method call: simply use `ForEach-Object` instead: `Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | ForEach-Object { $_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime) }`.