# How to use a Where-Object on a Csv and get the output without header

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file which looks like below

```
Name
Jonh
Jimmy
Sunny
Dany
```

So to get compare the list of names in CSV file with another name i used the below command

```
$csv = $csv | where {$_.Name -ceq "Jimmy"}
```

I am getting output as below

```
Name
------
Jimmy
```

can I have just just have the output as

```
Jimmy
```

Instead of

```
Name
-------
Jimmy
```

**EDIT**: Formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select the values of one property on all objects of an array in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176815/select-the-values-of-one-property-on-all-objects-of-an-array-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in later versions of powershell you can simply call a property name from the results, like so:

```
$csv = ($csv | where {$_.Name -ceq "Jimmy"}).Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
$csv = $csv | where {$_.Name -ceq "Jimmy"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: This will work even in older powershell versions - so could be useful for compatibility.