# Powershell output as array

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Hello i have powershell command that looks like this.

```
$result = Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "Create customer tracking list" -Content $site_script -Description "Creates list for tracking customer contact information" | Out-String
```

And output like this

```
Id                  : xxx69add-xxd1-xx43-xxba-xxcd2fac8790
Title               : Create customer tracking list
Description         : Creates list for tracking customer contact information
Content             : xxx
Version             : 0
IsSiteScriptPackage : False
```

What I want to do is to take Id somehow from it but I don't know-how. I don't know how to output this as an array so i can use `$result[0]` or any other way how to extract it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Replace `Out-String` with `Select -Expand Id`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select the values of one property on all objects of an array in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/1701026). From PSv3+ you can also use [member enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375): `$result = (Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "Create customer tracking list" -Content $site_script -Description "Creates list for tracking customer contact information").Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Out-String` turns all the input into a string, so not very useful here.

Either enclose the expression in parentheses and reference the `Id` parameter with the `.` member access operator:

```bsh
$result = (Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "Create customer tracking list" -Content $site_script -Description "Creates list for tracking customer contact information").Id
```

Or grab the `Id` property value with `Select-Object`:

```bsh
$result = Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "Create customer tracking list" -Content $site_script -Description "Creates list for tracking customer contact information" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
```

... or by using `ForEach-Object` member invocation:

```bsh
$result = Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "Create customer tracking list" -Content $site_script -Description "Creates list for tracking customer contact information" |ForEach-Object Id
```