# Powershell array's ForEach doesn't return a System.array?

Tags: powershell

I noticed that when running `ForEach` on an array object and capturing the output to a new variable, the new variable is not of type System.array:

```
PS D:\Playground> $Arr = 1, 2, 3
PS D:\Playground> $Arr2 = $Arr.ForEach({$_})
PS D:\Playground> $Arr2.Gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Collection`1                             System.Object
```

Rather, it is of type `Collection'1`.

What is this type? Is it equivalent to an array?

BTW, this is not the same as with `ForEach-Object`:

```
PS D:\Playground> $Arr3 = $($Arr | ForEach-Object { $_ })
PS D:\Playground> $Arr3.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Comment: I started writing an answer but stopped again, because I'm not really sure what a satisfying answer would look like. When you ask "What is this type?", what exactly are you hoping to learn? It's namespace? Finding the documentation?

Comment: This uses the "magic" `ForEach` method that returns a [`Collection<PSObject>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1) (which is a very weird type to use, since it's intended as a base class -- but since it's not abstract, it is indeed possible to use it directly). No, this is not equivalent to an array, but because PowerShell mostly only cares if things are enumerable (not what the exact type is) and since `Collection` is indexable just like an array, that doesn't usually matter much.

Comment: `$i = { 'asd' }.Invoke()` => `$i.GetType()` => _Collection\`1_ => `$i[0].GetType()` => _string_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me build on [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s excellent comment:

- The [**`.ForEach()`** array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach), and its sister method, [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where), **return [`[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1)** collection instances rather than regular PowerShell arrays (`[object[]]`).

  - Unlike the related [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) / [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) *cmdlets*, **these methods *always* return a *collection*, even with only a *single* object**:

    ```sh
    # .ForEach() method:
    # Collection result even with single object.
    @(1).ForEach({ $_ }).GetType().Name # -> Collection`1

    # ForEach-Object cmdlet:
    # Single output object: received as-is.
    (@(1) | ForEach { $_ }).GetType().Name # -> Int32
    # Two or more output objects: array result (if captured / used in expression)
    (1, 2 | ForEach { $_ }).GetType().Name # -> Object[]
    ```
  - Note: These methods are examples of [intrinsic members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members), i.e. properties and methods **PowerShell exposes on *all* objects, irrespective of their type** (*unless* a *type-native* member of the same name exists, which takes precedence).
- In essence, this collection type ***behaves like* an array** in PowerShell (due to implementing the [`[System.Collections.Generic.IList[psobject]]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.IList-1) interface):

  - Its elements are *enumerated* in the pipeline, just as an array's elements are.
  - *Positional indexing* (e.g. `[0]`) is supported, just as with arrays.
  - ***Unlike* an array, however**:

    - It is *resizable*; that is, its instances allow you to add (`.Add()`) and remove (`.Remove()`) elements.
    - Its element type is [`[psobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSObject) (not [`[object]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object)), the *usually* invisible *helper type* capable of wrapping any .NET object, which PowerShell employs (largely) behind the scenes.

      - Typically, this difference won't matter, but - unfortunately - there are edge cases where it does - see [GitHub issue #5579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5579).

---

**The `.ForEach()` *method* vs. the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet***:

Note: The following applies analogously to `.Where()` vs. `Where-Object`.

- Use `ForEach-Object` on *command* output, in order to benefit from the *streaming* behavior of the PowerShell pipeline (one-by-one processing, as input is being received, no need for up-front collection of input); e.g.:

  ```sh
  Get-ChildItem -Name *.txt| ForEach-Object { "[$_]" }
  ```
- Use `.ForEach()` on arrays (collections) that are *already are / can be collected in memory as a whole first*, if *faster* processing is called for; e.g.:

  ```sh
  ('foo.txt', 'bar.txt').ForEach({ "[$_]" })
  ```

Beware of the differences in single-object behavior and output-collection type discussed
above, however.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/45375) for a detailed juxtaposition of `.ForEach()`, `ForEach-Object`, the [`foreach` *statement*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach), as well as [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

Comment: I learnt the `foreach` method can be used on any object just a few days ago, also didn't know `.foreach({ begin {...} process {...} end {...} })` was possible. Another reason to not use `ForEach-Object` ever again lol

Comment: @Santiago, and I didn't know that something like `(1, 2).foreach({ begin { 0 } process { "[$_]"  } end { 3 } })` works - thanks! Note that for streaming (memory-throttling) processing you'll still need `ForEach-Object`. Also, `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` could be much less of an execution-speed concern _if they were implemented efficiently_ - see [GitHub feature request #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982).