# PowerShell Hashtable - how to select property

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I need to get the value of an environment variable from a kubernetes pod. I have my values listed in a hash table.

I call
`$hash["service-testurl"].spec.template.spec.containers.env`
And it returns a table:

```
name                                            value
----                                            -----
ADDR                                      https://test.com
TOKEN                                     123456789
CERT_PATH                                 public-certs/test
ENVIRONMENT                               dev
```

I need to get https://test.com into a variable in my ps1 script, but i'm not sure how to get this value. (consider that for each deployment the url will be different, like abc.com, def.com, ghj.com... so i can't filter by the name test.com)

I was looking for something like `$hash["service-testurl"].spec.template.spec.containers.env.name["ADDR"].value`

Running `$hash["service-testurl"].spec.template.spec.containers.env.PSTypeNames` returns

```
System.Object[]
System.Array
System.Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement [your own effective solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74377435/45375):

Even though your display output of `$hash["service-testurl"].spec.template.spec.containers.env` ***looks like* the representation of a (single) [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)**, the value is **actually**:

- (a) **an *array***, as your diagnostic output with `.pstypenames` demonstrates,
- (b) **whose elements are (presumably) `[pscustomobject]` instances that each have a a `.name` and a `.value` property** (an easy way to tell is that the display output's column headers are `name` and `value`, whereas with hashtables they would be `Name` and `Value`).

Leaving aside that the identifier `ADDR` is a property *value* rather than a property / key *name* in your case, you fundamentally cannot use *key-based index notation* (`['ADDR']`) on an *array* - that generally only works on a (single) hashtable (or, more generally, dictionary).<sup>[1]</sup>

In your case, **you need to find the array element whose `.name` property value is `'ADDR'`, which then allows you to return its `.value` property value**.

For collections already in memory, **the [intrinsic `.Where()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where)** (as used in your own solution) is a **more efficient - and more flexible - alternative** to filtering a collection via the **[`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) *cmdlet***.

It will often not matter in practice, but you can *optimize* a `.Where()` call to stop filtering once the *first* match has been found, if you expect or are only interested in *one* match:

```bash
$hash["service-testurl"].spec.template.spec.containers.env.Where(
  { $_.name -eq 'ADDR' },
  'First'
).value
```

<sup>Note that `.Where()` *always* returns an *array*-like collection, even if only a single value is matched - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70535552/45375) for details. As such, the `.value` property access is attempted *on that collection*, which, however, still works as intended, courtesy of the PowerShell feature known as [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration).</sup>

Note how using **`(...)` around the arguments** is now a *syntactic necessity*.

While with only a *single* argument - the filter script block (`{ ... }`) - you can *get away with* not using `(...)` - `.Where{ $_.name -eq 'ADDR' }` as shorthand for `.Where({ $_.name -eq 'ADDR' })` - **omitting the `(...)` is problematic** for two reasons:

- Given that the `Where-Object` *cmdlet* can *also* be referred to as `Where` (via a built-in alias), the two command forms could be confused, and given that `Where-Object` allows and is typically used with a *space* separating the command name from its script-block argument (e.g, `1..3 | Where { $_ -eq 2 }`, it is tempting to also try to use a space with the `.Where()` *method*, which does *not* work:

  ```bash
  # !! BROKEN, due to space before "{"
  (1..3).Where { $_ -eq 2 }
  ```
- If you add another argument later, you need to remember to use `(...)`

---

<sup>[1] The fact that key-based index notation does *not* work with [*member-access enumeration*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), i.e. doesn't work on an *array* of hashtables (only *dot notation* does, which PowerShell supports for hashtables too) could be considered an inconsistency; e.g. `@( @{ foo=1 } ).foo` works (dot notation), but `@( @{ foo=1 } )['foo']` does *not*, due to the array wrapper.

However, this inconsistency was declared to be by design - see [GitHub issue #17514](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17514).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it with something similar that @iRon proposed:

```
$hash["service-testurl"].spec.template.spec.containers.env.where{$_.name -eq 'ADDR'}.value
```

Thanks!