# Question about pipeline variables and pipeline shortcut(s)?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

In the creation of a script I'm writing, I ran across the use of what appears to be a pipeline shortcut that I have never seen before.

For example:

```
$acl | select -expandproperty Access | ? {$_.IdentityReference -eq "AD\$Group"}

     can be shortened to

$acl.Access.Where({$_.IdentityReference -eq "AD\$Group"})
```

What is this?  $acl.Access makes sense to me as it's just a property reference but I do not see any such .Where() method being available on this object.  As such it seems .Where({}) is some sort of pipeline shortcut for " | Where-Object {}".  Where can I find documentation for such a thing?  Do others like this exist?

**Second question**.  I have a need to add a calculated property to my results, and within the property expression I have to perform piping as well, so where I would typically just reference $_ from the parent pipeline, this is lost within the expression statement.

I can get around this by using -PipelineVariable up within the pipeline, but it seems this only works when used with cmdlets and is not available when starting a pipeline with a variable (which I do often).  Is there a way around this?

This works:

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path "AD:\$dn"
$acl | select -expandproperty access -PipelineVariable AccessRight | ? {$_.IdentityReference -eq "AD\$Group"} | select *, @{N='ObjectTypeName';E={($ADGuidMap.GetEnumerator() | ? {$_.Value -eq $AccessRight.ObjectType}).Name}}
```

I'd really like to be able to do this with the shortcut as anywhere I can shorten my oneliner I would like to do.  Unfortunately the following will not work as I cannot use pipelinevariable at this location.

```
$acl.Access.Where({$_.IdentityReference -eq "AD\$Group"}) -PipeLineVariable AccessRight | select *, @{N='ObjectTypeName';E={($ADGuidMap.GetEnumerator() | ? {$_.Value -eq $AccessRight.ObjectType}).Name}}
```

It's always bugged me about not being able to use Pipeline variables outside of cmdlets so I finally figured I'd ask if there was some sort of way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the *first* question:

- The [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) and [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach) *methods* are [*intrinsic members*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members), i.e. members that PowerShell implicitly makes available on objects of *any* type.
- While they function *similarly* to their *cmdlet* counterparts, [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), there are important differences.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70535552/45375) for more information.

As an aside: You could have simplified your command even when using the `Where-Object` cmdlet, namely with [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax):

```bash
$acl.Access | Where-Object IdentityReference -eq "AD\$Group"
```

---

As for the *second* question:

Because the `.Where()` *method* isn't a *cmdlet*, you cannot use the [common 
`-PipelineVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-pipelinevariable) with it.

Given that `.Access` typically returns *multiple* objects, using the pipeline with `-PipelineVariable` enables an elegant solution.

If you do want to avoid the pipeline (operator), you can combine the `.Where()` and `.ForEach()` methods as follows, with the help of an intermediate (regular) variable:

```bash
$acl.Access.
  Where({ $_.IdentityReference -eq "AD\$Group" }).
  ForEach({
      $aclEntry = $_
      Select-Object -InputObject $aclEntry -Property *, 
        @{
          N = 'ObjectTypeName'
          E = { ($ADGuidMap.GetEnumerator().Where({ $_.Value -eq $aclEntry.ObjectType })).Name }
        }
    })
```

---

Update:

As you've discovered yourself, if you stick with a pipeline, you can combine `-PipeLineVariable` with [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) in order to capture each element of an array / collection in a pipeline variable as it flows through the pipeline, for use a later script block, as the following (contrived) example shows:

```bash
$array = 0..3
Write-Output $array -Pipeline arrayElement |
Where-Object { 0 -eq $_ % 2 } | # filter out odd numbers
 ForEach-Object { $_ + 1 } | # add 1
 ForEach-Object { "pipeline variable / `$_: $arrayElement / $_" }
```

Output, which shows that each element of input array `$array` was individually captured in pipeline variable `$arrayElement`:

```bash
pipeline variable / $_: 0 / 1
pipeline variable / $_: 2 / 3
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the information.  Just a clarification... so there's no way to use a pipelinevariable type situation if my command were to start with a simple variable, unless I do the intermediate variable within a foreach?

Comment: @MatthewMcDonald, if your command starts with a variable, you can also use that variable in the script blocks you pass to `.Where()` and `.ForEach()`. Here, the intermediate variable is needed to refer to the _element at hand_ that is part of the collection stored in the starting variable. In simple cases, you can just use `$_`, without the need for an intermediate variable, but here you need one because of the _nested_ `.Where()` call.

Comment: You know, I was thinking if this is simply tied to a function, I immediately ask myself if there was a cmdlet I could use that would output the variable and ended up trying Write-Output.  It worked!  `Write-Output $myvariable -pipelinevariable test`

Comment: Apologies for delayed response.  Yes.  Thank you.