# How to access the elements of an array nested inside a PSCustomObject?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, subset

The following object is a toy example to illustrate my question:

```
$food = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Category = "Fruits"; Items = @("Mango", "Pineapple", "Orange", "Tangerine")},
    [PSCustomObject]@{Category = "Cities"; Items = @("Abidjan", "Douala")},
    [PSCustomObject]@{Category = "Animals"; Items = @("Dog", "Bird", "Cat")}
)

$food

Category Items
-------- -----
Fruits   {Mango, Pineapple, Orange, Tangerine}
Cities   {Abidjan, Douala}
Animals  {Dog, Bird, Cat}
```

I would like to access all items of the `"Fruits"` category, for example. I tried to first determine the index of `"Fruits"` in the `Category` property then use it in the `"Items"` property. I thought that the entire array of fruit names would be returned; however, it did not work as expected:

```
$i = $food.Category.IndexOf("Fruits")
$food[$i]
$food.Items[$i]

Mango
```

How should I go about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply index `$i` *to the `$food` array itself*, not to `.Items`:

```bash
$food[$i].Items # -> @('Mango', 'Pineapple', 'Orange', 'Tangerine')
```

However, a more PowerShell-idiomatic solution, using the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet to perform the category filtering (with [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax)), would be:

```bash
($food | Where-Object Category -eq Fruits).Items
```

Note:

- The above could potentially return *multiple* elements from the `$food` array, namely if more than one element has a `.Category` property value `'Fruits'`.
- To limit output to the *first* element, you could append a `Select-Object -First 1` pipeline segment, but there's a simpler alternative: the [intrinsic `.Where()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) has an overload that allows you to stop at the *first* match:<sup>[1]</sup>

  ```bash
  $food.Where({ $_.Category -eq 'Fruits' }, 'First').Item
  ```

  - It is somewhat unfortunate that the `Where-Object` cmdlet doesn't have an analogous feature; [GitHub issue #13834](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13834) suggests enhancing the `Where-Object` *cmdlet* to ensure feature parity with its *method* counterpart, `.Where()`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

```bash
$food.Items[$i]
```

Accessing `.Items` on the *array* stored in `$food` performs [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration).

That is, the `.Items` property on *each object stored in the array* is accessed, and the resulting values are returned as a *single, flat array of all such property values*.

- To spell it out: `$food.Items` returns the following array:

  ```bash
  @('Mango', 'Pineapple', 'Orange', 'Tangerine', 'Abidjan', 'Douala', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'Cat')
  ```
- As an aside: Your index-finding code, `$food.Category.IndexOf("Fruits")`, also makes use of member-access enumeration, relying on returning the `.Category` property values across all elements of the `$food` array.

Indexing into the resulting array (with `[$i]`, with `$i` being `0`) then only extracts its *first element*, i.e. `'Mango'`.

---

<sup>[1] Using the `.Where()` method has additional implications: (a) the input object(s) must be collected in full, up front, and (b) what is output is invariably a *collection*, namely of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70535552/45375) for details.</sup>

Comment: Your very detailed answer is very much appreciated. Being able to understand the inner workings of PowerShell in this context definitely helps a lot.

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer was helpful, @SavedByJESUS; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over each element in the `$food` array to find the object having a property with `Category` equal to `Fruits` then expand the `Items` property. The 3 most commonly used filtering techniques in PowerShell are:

1. [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3):

   ```bash
   $food | Where-Object Category -EQ Fruits |
      ForEach-Object Items
   ```
2. [`.Where` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#where):

   ```bash
   $food.Where({ $_.Category -eq 'Fruits' }).Items
   ```
3. A classic `foreach` loop with an `if` condition:

   ```bash
   foreach ($item in $food) {
       if ($item.Category -eq 'Fruits') {
           $item.Items
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me all these alternative solutions. I will study them.