# Powershell - use only one attribute from object

Tags: powershell

I need to call a script, which gets the status of the last backup (`Get-WBJob -Previous 1`) and use attribute `HResult` (will be 0 or 1) in the next step.

[image: Example returned object from Get-WBJob]

I have:

```
$params = @{"ID"="811185195";
            "Server"="XAD";
            "success"="Here i need have result of HResult"}
```

How do I get the only the `HResult` property from `Get-WBJob`?

Comment: Depends on the object type. Maybe append `|Select-Object -ExpandProperty hresult` and write that to a variable

Comment: See also: [Select the values of one property on all objects of an array in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/1701026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**grouping operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#grouping-operator--) `()` (formerly called the **group-expression operator**) to operate on the returned object by the grouped expression. For example:

```
$hResult = ( Get-WBJob -Previous 1 ).HResult
```

You can assign this to a variable as shown above, or simply set the result of the expression in the Hashtable itself:

```
$params = @{
  ID     = "811185195"
  Server = "XAD"
  Success = ( Get-WBJob -Previous 1 ).HResult
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Select-Object -ExpandProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) as well, instead of wrapping the inner expression in parentheses:

```
Get-WBJob -Previous 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HResult
```