# Extracting specific data from a string based on value using PS

Tags: string, powershell

I am creating a reporting tool for O365 using PS. My current issue is when grabbing any existing proxy adresses for a user I get the following data.

```
smtp:1stline@hatchellwood.onmicrosoft.com smtp:1stline@hatchell.com SMTP:1stline@hatchellwood.com SIP:1stline@hatchellwood.com SPO:SPO_024de2bf-d843-48e0-938d-fb6cfa8dcdbc@SPO_1fef7b7b-eef2-4533-b45e-f7f842c9f6a7
```

I need to take the data only preceded by 'smpt' and remove the rest. I can't use the substring function due to the length of the substrings being random. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to approach this?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Text = 'smtp:1stline@hatchellwood.onmicrosoft.com smtp:1stline@hatchell.com SMTP:1stline@hatchellwood.com SIP:1stline@hatchellwood.com SPO:SPO_024de2bf-d843-48e0-938d-fb6cfa8dcdbc@SPO_1fef7b7b-eef2-4533-b45e-f7f842c9f6a7'
($Text |Select-String '(?<=smtp:)\S+(?!=\S)' -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

```
1stline@hatchellwood.onmicrosoft.com
1stline@hatchell.com
1stline@hatchellwood.com
```

Comment: This doesn't return anything - I swapped the $a variable with the object variable holding the data above

Comment: Maybe my question was wrong then, if I try run this command I still get a no return. My data comes from an object I've grabbed from the Exchange module on a O365 tenant.
 EmailAddresses
--------------
{smtp:A.Gibson@hatchellwood.onmicrosoft.com, SMTP:A.Gibson@hatchellwood.com, SIP:A.Gibson@hatchellwood.com, SPO:SPO_eb33fd9c-d0ae-417b-afb0-99a64d9f59c7@SPO_1fef7b7b-eef2-4533-b45e-f7f842c9f6a7}

I need it to be case sensitive as well as the STMP and stmp are different types. :/

Comment: Note that I change the regular expression a bit at the last entry might not be closed with a space (`\s`) but anything that is **not** something else then a non-space (`\S`) which includes *nothing*.

Comment: No that part is great thank you I think it may be the actual data I'm passing into it. I use the Get-Mail cmdlet and take the EmailAddresses property which I'm assuming is technically not a string? Sorry very new to powershell.

Comment: $Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox
$mailHold = $Mailboxes | Where-Object{$_.PrimarySmtpAddress -like $UserAboutInfo.UserPrincipalName}
$UserMail = $mailHold | Select-Object EmailAddresses

So that returns the value I put earlier with the various smtp,SMTP,SPO etc

Comment: See [Select the values of one property on all objects of an array in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5176815/1701026)

Comment: Ok so I now have a System.Array rather than an object thank you.

Comment: I do not have access to this `Get-Mailbox` cmdlet, but the property name **EmailAddress*es*** suggests that it is multi-value. Meaning that you might just  do something like: `$mailHold | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses -like 'smpt:*'`

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is any better than [iRon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73555229/11025476), but for those who prefer to split strings:

```
$ProxyAddresses = 'smtp:1stline@hatchellwood.onmicrosoft.com smtp:1stline@hatchell.com SMTP:1stline@hatchellwood.com SIP:1stline@hatchellwood.com SPO:SPO_024de2bf-d843-48e0-938d-fb6cfa8dcdbc@SPO_1fef7b7b-eef2-4533-b45e-f7f842c9f6a7'
@(-split $ProxyAddresses) -match '^smtp:' -replace '^smtp:'
```